# Cannot install the DevKit

Tags: ruby, devkit

I've installed ruby 2.3.0. 
Now I'm trying to install the DevKit from this link: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads =>
DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe
Unpacked it to C:\DevKit.
and here's a problem:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DFzt.jpg)

please, tell me what's wrong, I can't fix it by myself...

Comment: That's the 64-bit devkit.  Did you install the x64 version of ruby?

Comment: yes, I have ruby 2.3.0 x64

Comment: FWIW: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#mix-and-matching-of-rubyinstaller-with-cygwin-will-fail

Comment: I'm using file named msys.

Comment: i looked for files with key word "Cygwin" and found some. Shoud I delete them?

Answer (score 0):

oooh, I fixed it. That was veeeery stupid mistake. All the problem was in the path of my ruby. I installed it into Rubymine directory, so my console couldn't find it. I reinstalled it into my C:\ drive and DevKit worked well!